# Update Facebook status via Atom feed

Tags: facebook, google-plus, atom

I'm currently using [PlusFeed](http://plusfeed2.appspot.com/) to get an Atom feed of my public Google+ stream, which I'm then posting to Facebook via [RSS Graffiti](http://www.facebook.com/RSS.Graffiti) (other similar apps are available). The problem is, RSS Graffiti and similar apps post the resulting message as a Facebook Note (with title, body, etc) rather than my actual status.

Is there an app available that can update my *status* from an Atom feed? (Especially [now that Facebook has increased the character limit for a status from 420 to 5000 characters](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/facebook/facebook-increases-status-update-character-limit-to-5000/3907))

The absolute ideal would be for the app to post my Google+ post as my Facebook status if it's within the character limit and as a note otherwise, but perhaps that's a stretch too far at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this *If This Then That* recipe: http://ifttt.com/recipes/1813. If that's not quite what you want, there's many more to choose from.

Comment: Thanks. That particular one creates a link post as opposed to a status update but I'll have a look through, looks like a good resource

Comment: Brilliant - created my own task on IFTT to do what I was after. Works well, thanks very much